# how do i use runpod to deploy a webapp that sends and receive http request

Tags: large-language-model, webui

want to deploy a runpod CPU server in which i have a webapp that provides UI and sends/receives request to a runpod serverless llm service for LLM inferance.

Is there any existing simple web ui app that basically routes the http request.

i dont want to use llm text generation web ui, which has too much functionality and is too complicated. I just want to have a simple webui app example